# Excel: Next immediate bigger value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column such as

```
1231
1222
1230
1212
1220
1236
1220
1224
1240
```

In the next column I expect the resultant to be,

```
1236
1230
1236
1220
1236
1240
1224
1240
NA
```

Thus, the next immediate bigger value WITHOUT SORTING.

Is there a way around with excel inbuilt functions and not use a scripting language to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `A1:A9`, **array formula**** in `B1`:

`=INDEX(A1:A$9,MATCH(TRUE,A1:A$9>A1,0))`

Copy down as required.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*